# Mobile Media Queries

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I have a [website](http://agrilife.co.nz) that I need to have working on mobile devices currently it displays like the image below.

So far I have had the following ideas:

1. Copy the 680 lines of CSS again within the same document in between `@media only screen` tags.
2. Copy the same code into a mobile.css stylesheet and start again

"2" is my least favourite option but the most likely I am just wanting to know what your options would be?

**iPhone View:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's going to take a little work but is worth it. You have to take the CSS that is too big on mobile and put them in specific media queries based on size. Let's say you want your titles to change from 80px to 40px when the screen size is less than 600px:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
.mytitle {
   font-size: 80px;
   }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.mytitle {
   font-size: 40px;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Put this in the head of your HTML

```
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1 />
```

Comment: it is and its not doing much

Comment: it should work properly if you are adding the above mentioned in the head part of your html. <meta name="viewport"  content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/> . Also are you using jquerymobile?

Comment: @shemy No I am not but the website link is linked to the site in question so feel free to take a look